# Unable to create new TFS 2010 project w/ SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-2010

When attempting to create a new TFS 2010 team project with a SharePoint portal, I get the following message:

TF218017: A SharePoint site could not be created for use as the team project portal. The following error ocurred: TF250044: A SharePoint site cannot be created at the following location: http://XXXX/sites/DefaultCollection/XXXXXX. The following user account does not have the required permissions in SharePoint Products to create a site at that location: DOMAIN\USER. The user account must have sufficient permissions to create a sub-site on the following site: http://XXXX/sites/DefaultCollection/XXXXXX.

I read a suggestion somewhere that mentioned adding my account to the Site collection administrators of the DefaultCollection.  Step 1 was navigating to http://XXXX/sites/DefaultCollection... well, that failed with a big ol' "Error: Access Denied"

I have access to the TFS Administration Console and have been told I am an administrator w/ full privileges. Unfortuneately, the consultant that setup TFS is no longer with us.

Any suggestions for troublehsooting this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I too had thus trouble, and after some rather arcane searching with google found the following: http://lifeaccordingtoabel.blogspot.ca/2009/08/create-team-project-failure-and.html

Essentially, you have to add your user as having Full Control in the DefaultCollection share point site first, then add your user as having full control in the Sharepoint Central Administration tool as well.

Comment: To access the DefaultCollection share point site, I first need to get access to http://XXXX/sites/DefaultCollection. He is getting an access denied there as well. I am having the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: This actually worked for me. Strangely though, I had to start Visual Studio as an Admin afterwards (I got such an error message when trying again after giving myself permissions as described). Also, I worked locally on the TFS.. that probably is not standard.. (also, the Admin account there is Admin for everything.. Windows, TFS, Sharepoint, SQL (yes, it is the TFS Demo Hyper-V machine from MS)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Team Foundation Server Administration Console, navigate to "%Server%\Application Tier\SharePoint Web Applications" and add your domain account to the "Service Accounts for SharePoint Web Applications". This should grant you access to the SharePoint sites.

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting the "Access denied" message.

Answer (score 0):

you have to go the site collection and add the user as site collection administrator. each new team project will create a sub site under the root so the user must have the permissions on it. neither the service account or farm admin will solve this problem.